# Find object in image using c#

Tags: c#, .net, image, object

Im looking for some code or example on how to find an object in an image.  Lets say I take a picture of myself is it possible to get the pixel info (color and size ) on my shirt that I am wearing? I know this might be a far out question but was wondering if its is possible.  I have the Aforge.net dlls but don't really know how to use it especially for this demo.

Comment: In my experience, MatLab's image processing toolbox is much more useful for this. That said, I don't know much about doing it in c#

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code for Haar feature detection using C#:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441226/Haar-feature-Object-Detection-in-Csharp

If you're not married to C# you could also try SimpleCV for Haar feature detection using python.